# Poor performance of simple webservice

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-services, jmeter

My question is about the performance of a simple test website.

For testing the performance I use [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which is simulating 75 users on this page (continuously).
The page is only doing a webservice call to GetHello() and prints the result.

The webservice method doesn't do much:

```
public string GetHello(){
    int count = 0;
    foreach(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
       count++;
    }
    return "hello world "+ count;
}
```

But in the performance results I see the average load time is becoming higher and higher... that don't seems logical to me. I don't know where to look to solve this problem.

The server for the website (2 quad core processors 2.33Ghz, 8G memory) memory and CPU is not busy, the server for the webservice (same hardware setup as the website server) memory is not busy but the CPU usage is between 60% and 100%...

The things I think of is IIS setting problem or a web.config configuration (for the website or webservice) But I can't find any solution for this... or an explanation why this happens.
This kind of simple code should never be a problem in my eyes?

Update:
When I remove the loop from the webservice... there is no problem as it seems. So as soon there is a little calculation needed in the webservice method the average processing time increases.

---

**Update 2**

*Case slow performance*

We are running into performance issues with our website.
We’ve setup a test environment to determine where the problems occur.
The test environment consist of 3 servers. (2 for the front-end (website) en 1 for the back-end (wcf webservices)).
The specs of the servers:

- Website 1: Intel Xeon e5410 (2x) 8GB ram
- Website 2: Intel Xeon x3323 4GB ram
- Webservice: Intel Xeon e5410 (2x) 8GB ram

The webservices are using net.tcp endpoints
With Jmeter we’re sending 75 concurrent request to 1 page on website 1.
The responsetimes keep increasing around 5 sec and then leveling off.
When we go to website 1 with the browser, the website has high response times.
When we go to website 2, same page, the website is fast.
With netstat –t we can see that website 1 only has around 30 connections to the webservice. 
The endpoint binding in the web.config on the website is as follow:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />  
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="netTCPBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" sendTimeout="00:03:00" closeTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" maxConnections="65355">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None"></security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.1.124:21130/ContentService.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTCPBinding" contract="ContentWS.IContentService" name="Default1">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.1.124:21131/Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTCPBinding" contract="PrijsvrijWS.IService" name="Default">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the config of the webservice:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>      
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="netTCPBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" sendTimeout="00:03:00" closeTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:03:00" maxConnections="65355">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None"></security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings> 
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ajaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="serviceWithMetadata">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceWithMetadata" name="WcfService.Service">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:21131/Service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTCPBinding" name="Default" contract="WcfService.IService" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceWithMetadata" name="WcfService.ContentService">
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:21130/ContentService.svc" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTCPBinding" name="Default" contract="WcfService.IContentService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

We tried servicethrottling, but it doesn’t seem to have effect.
During the test CPU usage on the servers is as follow:

- Website 1: around 60%, with max 90%
- Website 2: 1%
- Webservice: around 25%, with max 50%

Are we running at the max of the website 1 or are we missing some settings?

Comment: I think that "guessing" where the issue is, is an exercise in futility. What you need to do is get a tool like `Ants Profiler` and run it on both sides and see if there is an issue with hot paths in the code, or maybe memory leaks. If not, you can start thinking about IIS. I would look at your own code first. You can get a 14 day trail version, to get you rolling. Just my two cents.

Comment: I agree about looking at my own code first... but there is almost no code. The webservice is what you see in my post and the website only calls this webservice.

Comment: Sure, but this is a **Compute bound operation**, which means that it will tie up the thread until the operation is finished. All the other requests are just sitting and waiting for the CPU to free up in order to service their request.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't a 'heavy' operation... and only with 75 concurrent users. That is not something I would imagine to be to much for any server.

Comment: It's not an issue of how heavy the operation is, it's a simple issue of time and math. You can service at most 1 computationally intensive request per core. So if you have a quad core machine that means you have 4 concurrent requests that can be handled. If those operations take even 100ms, then each subsequent request that comes in will have to wait for the previous ones to finish. If you have 40 concurrent requests, the last 4 users will be waiting close to a second before their request is handled.

Comment: Yes I get that. But is it 'normal' then for a website that uses a webservice you can only process that little amount of concurrent users?

Comment: @Josh - In Intel architecture there are two threads per core, so 4 cores would be 8 threads. Some parts of the pipeline are shared, so it isn't really 8 threads, but... just saying :)

Comment: If you are doing computationally intensive work then yes. Normally you would set up a separate cluster of application servers for that kind of thing. Otherwise most web services are usually just accessing some info from a DB, doing a tiny bit of processing and sending it across the wire. So the time spent on the CPU is minimal at best.

Comment: @EladLachmi - Yeah I get you :) Just wanted to show the basic calculations.

Comment: @BvdVen - Yes, this is normal, and is a real issue for large-scale production systems with compute bound operations. What you could do is off-load the math from the thread handeling the request to a thread from the thread pool using `Task` objects. This will not solve your problem completely,since the `Task`s will still be bound to a CPU. It will allow seperation of the HTTP processing from the CPU bound threads, so these can happen in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked JMeter JVM's health? Some times JVM GC may be the cause for high response which we overlook.

Comment: The JMeter isn't running on the same machine as the tested website or webservice is running

Comment: Eventhough JMeter is not running on the same machine as the tested website, JMeter can suffer from GC issues which in turn causing high response times. Use some tools like jvmtop from google - https://code.google.com/p/jvmtop/ to check the JVM health of JMeter.